# .htaccess rewriterule does not work with https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my simple .htaccess
My goal is simply to add a rule that redirects /faq -> faq.php on my HTTPS server.

```
# force ssl
RewriteCond    %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
RewriteRule faq faq.php
```

I also tried with:

```
RewriteRule faq faq.php
RewriteCond    %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

This works fine if I uncomment the http->https redirection rule.

so what I try to do is:

> ->if http, then redirect to https
>
> ->if /faq  then redirect to faq.php

When I remove these lines

```
RewriteCond    %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

faq->faq.php works but I lose the http->https redirection of my whole website

Comment: All your rules are uncommented as per your question. What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

You should have at least one `RewriteCond` for each `RewriteRule`.

Try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/faq$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/faq.php [R]
```

after the **first two** lines (instead of the third).

EDIT:

As I meant, it was

```
RewriteCond    %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/faq$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/faq.php [R]
```

That is, TWO `RewriteCond` directives.

Comment: Not working: it only works for : http://example.com/faq ->https://example.com/faq.php BUT NOT for https://example.com/faq ->https://example.com/faq.php (works for HTTP redirection, not for HTTPS redirection)

Comment: That must be that you have it in a `VirtualHost` directive that does not have `Listen 443` option. If you use a separate `VirtualHost` directive for SSL, you must put this latter into that directive, not in the "default" on port 80.

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? My site works fine with HTTPS . Problem is, looks like .htaccess have no effect on https, only on http

Comment: Ah. Try placing the FAQ related two lines before the HTTPS lines (that is, swap the two line pairs).

Comment: I did try that already ! I goit a 404 error when trying to fetch /faq instead of faq.php ! It works when I disable the http to https redirection !

Comment: Could you please post your whole current .htaccess file, with all possible IfModule directives?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/faq$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/faq.php [R]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

But I tried all combinations possible already !

Comment: You should use `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` instead of `off`.
It is not guaranteed to have value `off`, only `on` or nothing.

Comment: I edited the question and included 2 versions. But I also have tested your version with no same poor result.

Comment: Just tried with !on : same thing. 404 not found (http->https is ok)

Comment: I have a clue: when I put deny all : it denies on http but still works on https. That means : .htaccess is totally ignored when site is https !

Comment: It might also mean that AllowOverride is not enabled for Options.
Or your VirtualHost.
Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: found: inserted              <Directory /var/www/html>
                         AllowOverride all
                </Directory> into /etc/apache2/sites-enabled# nano default-ssl.conf
The only little problem to be fixes is that url address shows now faq.php: I would like it to be /faq. Any idea ?